# Display dirs tree based on a file content

Tags: bash, regex, grep, find, tree

```
$ find ./ | tac

./dir1/file -> "abc"
./dir1
./dir2/file - > "abc"
./dir2
./dir3/file -> "xyz"
./dir3/dir3_1/file  - > "abc"
./dir3/dir3_1
./dir3
```

or

```
$ tree

├── dir1
│   └── file -> "abc"
├── dir2
│   └── file -> "abc"
└── dir3
    ├── dir3_1
    │   └── file -> "abc"
    └── file -> "xyz"
```

I need to display a **dirs tree** (without files) only these that have a "file" file containing "abc" value.

I know there is a command `tree -P 'file*'` to filter the tree by filename, maybe there is also a method to filter the tree by "grepping" a content.

I also came up with the idea to do something like this (of course it doesn't work):

```
   $(find ./ -type f -exec grep abc {} +;) | tree -d
```

and somehow send flat `find` results to to `tree` command.

Comment: So you only want to recurse a directory and list sub-directories for files that have a value? Define your value, list your child-items, and do a `If this = this, this` style command to recurse a directory if matches your statement. You could append to a file and `cat` that at the end, if easier.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `tree --fromfile`

In my Debian 10 I have `tree v1.8.0`. It supports `--fromfile`.

> `--fromfile`
>   Reads a directory listing from a file rather than the file-system. Paths provided on the command line are files to read from rather than directories to search. The dot (`.`) directory indicates that `tree` should read paths from standard input.

This way I can feed `tree` with output from `find` or `grep -rl`:

```
grep -rl abc | tree -d --fromfile .
```

Problems:

- `.` will be reported even if there is no matching file at all.
- If `tree` reads `/foo/whatever` or `foo/whatever` then `foo` will be reported as a *subdirectory* of `.`. Similarly with `./whatever`: `.` will be reported as an *additional* level named `.`. So if you use `grep -rl abc /foo`, `grep -rl abc .`, `find /foo` or `find .` then the results may not entirely meet your formal expectations.
- Filenames with newlines will confuse `tree`. Using `grep -Z` or `find -print0` is not an option because there is no corresponding switch for `tree`.
- A matching file inside `foo/bar/` together with a matching file inside `foo/` will generate the same output as the matching file in `foo/bar/` alone. If you see the `foo/bar` branch then you cannot know if there's a matching file in `foo/`. This is a flaw in your specification.

---

#### Alternative approach

The following code doesn't use `--fromfile`. It fixes some of the above problems but it's slower.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
[ "$?" -eq 0 ] || exit 2
trap 'rm -r "$tmp"' INT TERM EXIT
dir="${2:-.}"

cd "$dir" || exit 1

find . -type f -exec grep -q "$1" {} \; -exec sh -c '
   cd "$1" || exit 1
   shift 1
   for d; do
      mkdir -p "top/$(dirname "$d")"
   done
' sh-find "$tmp" {} +

cd "$tmp" || exit 1
[ -d "top" ] || exit 0
printf "%s\n" "$dir"
tree -d --noreport "top" | tail -n +2
```

Usage: `scriptname pattern /path/to/dir` or `scriptname pattern` (then `.` is the default directory).

The general procedure is as follows:

1. Create a temporary directory.
2. For each matching file create directories inside the temporary directory, so the relative paths correspond. This way the desired directory structure is built inside the temporary directory.
3. Use `tree -d` in the temporary directory (adjusting the output, so the original directory path replaces the temporary top node).
4. Remove the temporary directory.

Note a directory named `top` will be crated if and only if there's at least one match. This way we can tell if there was a match. Empty output (with exit status `0`) indicates there was no match at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have got Debian 9 and there is a tree there without --fromfile. I'll try your script, but maybe it's also time to upgrade distribution :-)